# How to load the next video before the first video ends using mediaElement?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a single video and I want to repeat the video forever; however, I want the video to repeat before it has completely ended. Unfortunately, the event `MediaEnded` fires only when the video has finished the video. I am looking for some kind a event like ending, or play, or something like that to do this operation.

```
string VideoFileLocation = sVideoLocation + @"\video\";
DirectoryInfo df = new DirectoryInfo(VideoFileLocation);

media_Figura1.Source = new Uri(VideoFileLocation + @"\Figuras_loop.mov");
media_Figura1.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;

if (df.Exists)
{
    media_Figura1.Play();
}
else
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("No se puede cargar el video loop (Figura1)", "Casino Krown");
}

private void media_Figura1_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    media_Figura1.UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;

    if (bLoop_1Figura)
    {
        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        media_Figura1.Position = ts;
    }
}
```

I also would like to leave the last frame of the video visible when it ends instead of the default black screen. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for mor easily solution, you could have 2 videos, 2 mediaElements, and, when the first videoEnded, repeat both mediaElementes media files, and, you can usea a bool variable for determinate how video can play it all second video and stop the first video.

you can use [this solution](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tk2VrFB1qSg) and read the comment of video.